# How to revoke certificates, or generate CRL files with Keytool

Tags: openssl, java, certificate-revocation, crl

I didn't find how to use java keytool to revoke certificates or generate CRL files.

Is it possible to do that with keytool?
If no, how to do it with openssl ?

Answer (score 1):

keytool does not provide the necessary functionality. As for openssl - there are several extensive documentations (like [this](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/certificate-revocation-lists.html)) which are [trivial to find](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+crl+openssl). It makes no sense to replicate everything here again.